# MySQL: Select min date with max hour

Tags: mysql, database

anybody know how to select in mysql min date, but with max hour of day , for example:
I have a set of dates:

```
[2015-01-02 00:00:00, 2015-01-03 09:00:00, 2015-01-02 19:00:00, 2015-02-01 14:00:00]
```

and i need to get `2015-01-02 19:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(myColumn) FROM myTable WHERE myColumn < (
  SELECT DATE(MIN(myColumn)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM myTable
)
```

Comment: Good solution.  This can take full advantage of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(date(datetime_col)) + interval max(hour(datetime_col)) hour
from your_table
```

Comment: Wow, you deduced all that from the information provided?

Comment: Close but not suitable. Interval max(hour(datetime_col)) return max hour from all dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by date(col) asc, col desc
limit 1;
```